# How to verify user email in Drupal 7 when registering user

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I want a user to enter email, password and password verification. After that they should receive an email notification with an activation URL. When they navigate to this URL, the account gets activated.Is there a Drupal 7 module for this? If not, how can I get started with coding it myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Luckily enough someone's already written this functionality, it's available in the [LoginToboggan module](http://drupal.org/project/logintoboggan)